# jQuery get attr id of an active image

Tags: jquery, image

Im stuck on some jquery, and I dont know why it isnt working...

```
$('img').click(function() {
    $('img').removeClass('bob');
    $(this).addClass('bob');
});

var test = $('img.bob').attr('src');
$('div.button').click(function() {
    alert(test);
});
```

basically i need to get the attr ID of the image selected, but the alert only returns 'null'.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Im pulling my hair out...

A.

Comment: for a start guessing you want `$('img.bob').attr('id');`

Comment: does: `$('div.button').click(function() { alert($('img.bob').attr('id')); });` work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember that the `click` event you assigned does not run until you actually click an `<img>`, so trying to get an image with the class `.bob` before any click events have occurred on the `<img>` elements will result in 0 elements matched (unless you have `.bob` assigned to one of the `<img>` elements before the page loads.

You need to retrieve the 'id' *inside* the button's click handler.

Also, you can make your code a little more efficient by caching the `<img>` elements found (as long as you're not adding additional ones dynamically after the page loads).

```
var $img = $('img').click(function() {
    $img.not(this).removeClass('bob');
    $(this).addClass('bob');
});

$('div.button').click(function() {
    var test = $img.filter('.bob').attr('id');
    alert(test);
});
```

If you are going to be adding images dynamically, then you don't need to cache them.

```
$('img').click(function() {
    $('img').not(this).removeClass('bob');
    $(this).addClass('bob');
});

$('div.button').click(function() {
    var test = $('img.bob').attr('id');
    alert(test);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$('div.button').click(function() {
    alert(this.id.ToString());
});
```